# Query for Option/Value Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which contains the options and values called "Option_Values". This will contain an option and a value, i.e.

Option = Property Type (ID:1)
Value = Detached (ID:1)

```
PropertyID   OptionID      ValueID
1             1           1
1             2           2
2             3           3
```

Tables: Option_Values (FK PropertyID), Properties (PK PropertyID), Options (PK OptionID), Values (PK ValueID)

What is the easiest way to access the options via a query?

i.e. My old query is like this SELECT * FROM Properties WHERE Option = Value, but as I have multiple rows for Properties, this is not working now.

What I want to be able to do is easily access any data within the Option_Values table, is it possible to do a simple INNER JOIN?

Thanks

Comment: What's your desired result set?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a distinct list?

select distinct (option_id) from table
or depending on your database "distinct" might be "unique".

Comment: SQL Server uses `distinct`, not unique, and it's a declarative word, not a function, so it'd be `select distinct option_id from table`.

Comment: you can still put parenthesis around it though. It's a style thing. I put parens because it looks and acts like a function.